# Accessing sender methods from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton, unrecognized-selector

I have 2 classes, ClassA and ClassB

ClassA calls ClassB's method : - (void)someMethod:(id)sender

in the above method, I need to grab the sender from ClassB (the sender is a subclass of UIView that has a UIButton on it) and update the button image using something along the lines of
[sender updateButtonImageWithImage:image]

(the UIView subclass has the method: - (void)updateButtonImageWithImage:(UIImage *) )

but whenever I call this from ClassB the app crashes with
[UIButton updateButtonImageWithImage:] unrecognized selector blah blah blah.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> the sender is a subclass of UIView that has a UIButton on it

This is incorrect—if the button is what’s triggering `-someMethod:`, then the *button*, not the view containing it, is the `sender` that gets passed into `-someMethod:`. The easiest way to do this would be to grab the button’s superview (which should be your view subclass), then call your `-updateButtonImageWithImage:` on that:

```
[(MyViewSubclass *)[sender superview] updateButtonImageWithImage:image];
```